# How to build a named list from tibble list columns?

Tags: r, list, tibble

Is there a straightforward, pipe-friendly way to generate a `list` object from a *tibble* that contains list-columns?

Consider the example below. If `my_starwars` is a given *tibble*, how can I achieve a **named** list like `desired_output`?

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)

my_starwars <-
  starwars %>%
  slice(1)

films <- my_starwars %>% pull(films) %>% set_names("films")
vehicles <- my_starwars %>% pull(vehicles) %>% set_names("vehicles")

desired_output <- c(films, vehicles)

desired_output
#> $films
#> [1] "The Empire Strikes Back" "Revenge of the Sith"    
#> [3] "Return of the Jedi"      "A New Hope"             
#> [5] "The Force Awakens"      
#> 
#> $vehicles
#> [1] "Snowspeeder"           "Imperial Speeder Bike"
```

Although the code above does the job, I want something less manual that can stem from the pipe, such as:

```r
my_starwars %>%
  build_list(films, vehicles, foo, bar) # this is a demo

## $films
## [1] "The Empire Strikes Back" "Revenge of the Sith"     "Return of the Jedi"      "A New Hope"              ## "The Force Awakens"      

## $vehicles
## [1] "Snowspeeder"           "Imperial Speeder Bike"

## $foo
## [1] "foo" "foo" "foo"

## $bar
## [1] "bar" "bar"
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this with `tidyverse` tools?

---

EDIT

---

Although the solution by @GuedesBF is great for the initial `my_starwars` example, it fails with a different type of tibble. So my original example was too minimal and not representative of my issue. Please consider the following example, in which `trb` is a tibble that holds 2 list-columns, with a `recipe` object in each.

```r
library(recipes)

car_rec_1 <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
  step_ns(disp, deg_free = 5)

car_rec_2 <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
  step_dummy(am)

trb <-
  tribble(~car_rec_1, ~car_rec_2,
           car_rec_1,  car_rec_2)

undesired_output_trb <- 
  trb %>%
  lapply(unlist)

car_rec_1 <- trb %>% pull(car_rec_1) %>% setNames("car_rec_1")
car_rec_2 <- trb %>% pull(car_rec_2) %>% setNames("car_rec_2")
desired_output_trb <- c(car_rec_1, car_rec_2)
```

When we use @GuedesBF's solution we get the `undesired_output_trb`, whereas what I want is `desired_output_trb`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop-apply a function to `unlist()` the `select`ed columns.

```
my_starwars %>%
        select(c(films, vehicles)) %>%
        lapply(unlist)

#Or if tidyverse is a must, we can replace `lapply` with `purrr::map`

my_starwars %>%
        select(c(films, vehicles)) %>%
        map(unlist)

$films
[1] "The Empire Strikes Back" "Revenge of the Sith"     "Return of the Jedi"      "A New Hope"              "The Force Awakens"      

$vehicles
[1] "Snowspeeder"           "Imperial Speeder Bike"
```

**Update**

The second example given by the OP contains nested lists, list columns with list elements inside. The simpler `lapply(unlist)` or `unclass()` solutions wont work here. We need an unlisting function that provides exra control, for which i would recommend `purrr::pluck`. `map(my_starwars, pluck, 1)` works for the original question too.

```
library(purrr)

trb %>%
        map(pluck, 1)

identical(desired_output_trb, trb %>% map(pluck, 1))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution gives unexpected results with a different kind of list-columns. Please see my edit. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Please see the updated answer, i think it is fine now

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70533418/6105259), another solution would be with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and `tibble::deframe()`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

my_starwars <-
  starwars %>%
  slice(1)

my_starwars %>%
  select(films, vehicles) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  deframe()
#> $films
#> [1] "The Empire Strikes Back" "Revenge of the Sith"    
#> [3] "Return of the Jedi"      "A New Hope"             
#> [5] "The Force Awakens"      
#> 
#> $vehicles
#> [1] "Snowspeeder"           "Imperial Speeder Bike"
```

---

```r
library(recipes)

car_rec_1 <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
  step_ns(disp, deg_free = 5)

car_rec_2 <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
  step_dummy(am)

trb <-
  tribble(~car_rec_1, ~car_rec_2,
          car_rec_1,  car_rec_2)

trb %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  deframe()
#> $car_rec_1
#> Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor         10
#> 
#> Operations:
#> 
#> Natural Splines on disp
#> 
#> $car_rec_2
#> Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor         10
#> 
#> Operations:
#> 
#> Dummy variables from am
```

Comment: `deframe` is excellent too, i forgot bout it, +1. But i think we can bypass the `pivot_longer` step, and use `map` here too, looks more natural. `trb %>% map(deframe)`